# .htaccess found in every folder

Tags: htaccess, dashboard

every week my site's every folder has .htaccess when try to open the site it gets a virus error. I remove .htaccess manually from every folder and then the site works. but after a few days, I got the same problem.
What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having the same issue on many of my sites.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few steps, even though you have to move in the process towards whatever is necessary.

- Step 1: Backup wp-contents folder and the files
- Step 2: Backup credentials at wp-config files
- Step 3: Find and delete unwanted plugins and theme files, if anything is suspicious.
- Step 4: Delete the default WordPress files other than wp-content folder.
- Step 5: Reupload those files manually and replace wp-config.php with the previous one, otherwise database connection error will happen.

These are the most common steps to get rid of a virus, depending on the type of script they are using, or the location of of infected file, your steps will differ.

If the attacker has planted a file in the server storage, and you are using a shared hosting, you might need to change your hosting to get rid of it.

Hope this helps.